# Left div fluid and fixed right (right jumping down)

Tags: html, css

I managed to make a fixed left and a fluid right, but when trying to do the opposite, the fixed right jumps down. I was pretty sure this was supposed to work, but apparently not.

I just can't understand why the fixed width right div is jumping down.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPXGvb

### html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left left--fixed"></div>
    <div class="right right--fluid"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="left left--fluid"></div>
    <div class="right right--fixed"></div>
</div>
```

### css

```
.container {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.left {
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
.right {
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}

.left--fixed {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.right--fluid {
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: auto;
}

.left--fluid {
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.right--fixed {
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Check this: http://bitsofco.de/2015/how-floating-works/

Comment: @Paulie_D Even if you reduce the width, the green div is down. The cause of the problem is due to the behavior of float.

Comment: You can put `right--fixed` before `left--fluid` to achieve this. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ejqgqd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why I love `flexbox` so much.

```css
.container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
}
.left {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}
.right {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}
.left--fixed {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}
.right--fixed {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left left--fixed"></div>
  <div class="right right--fluid"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left left--fluid"></div>
  <div class="right right--fixed"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although @daniel-stanley got the most upvotes, I've accepted this answer as the solution, because it doesn't change the order of elements in the html, which semantically I think is the most correct thing to do. Apparently I have to look into flexbox :)

Answer (score 2):

Position the float element first:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="right right--fixed"></div>
    <div class="left left--fluid"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.left {
 height: 100px;
 background: red;
}
.right {
 height: 100px;
 background: green;
}

.left--fixed {
 width: 100px;
 float: left;
}
.right--fluid {
 margin-left: 100px;
 width: auto;
}

.left--fluid {
 width: auto;
 overflow: hidden;  
}
.right--fixed {
 width: 100px;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="left left--fixed"></div>
    <div class="right right--fluid"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="left right--fixed"></div>
    <div class="right left--fluid"></div>
</div>
```

[CHeck out](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNmVVj)